# Iterator values in Scala vs cached values with vals

Tags: scala, iterator

I don't understand this behavior. I want to check if a value is in a circle created on a grid (as an array). Defining the two sides of the circle..

```
val circleLeft  = Vector(5,14,23..)
val circleRight = Vector(5,16,27,..)
```

I'm checking with the below function this condition. 
With the first one:

```
def insideCircle(idx: Int): Boolean = {
  val l = circleLeft.toIterator
  val r = circleRight.toIterator
  while (l.hasNext && r.hasNext) {
    if(idx < r.next && idx > l.next) return true
  }
  return false
}
```

It returns always true. With this second one

```
def insideCircle(idx: Int): Boolean = {
  val l = circleLeft.toIterator
  val r = circleRight.toIterator
  while (l.hasNext && r.hasNext) {
    val x1 = r.next
    val x2 = l.next
    println(x2,x1)
    if(idx < x1 && idx > x2) return true
  }
  return false
}
```

It works properly, i.e. insideCircle(15) = true, insideCircle(17) = false

Is there something here different..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&&` is called short-circuit method (in Scala it's implemented with by-name argument). In your first example `l.next` is only executed if `idx < r.next`. In the second example `l.next` is executed always.

**UPDATE**

I would suggest more functional way:

```
def insideCircle(idx: Int): Boolean = {
  val l = circleLeft.toIterator
  val r = circleRight.toIterator
  r.zip(l).find {
    case (x1, x2) =>
      idx < x1 && idx > x2
  }
  .isDefined
}
```

Comment: so, to make it an AND condition I should close the two conditions between parentheses? EDIT: 
Beautiful, thank you!

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, you need to _evaluate_ both `.next`s before calling `&&`. Compare `{ println("left"); false } && { println("right"); true }` and `{ println("left"); false } & { println("right"); true }` (`&` is not a short-circuit method)

Comment: "you need to evaluate both .nexts before calling &&" now I understand better, ok